# element-wise product matrix x matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How to do element-wise product by column, i am looking for a non-loop technique cause i have dozens of columns in each dataframe and different width size

example:

```
mat1=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,1,1],"b":[2,2,2]})
mat2=pd.DataFrame({"c":[1,1,1],"d":[1,2,3]})
```

output

```
  ac ad bc bd
0 1  1  2  2
1 1  2  2  4
2 1  3  2  6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([mat1.columns, mat2.columns])

df = mat1.reindex(mux,  axis=1, level=0).mul(mat2.reindex(mux,  axis=1, level=1))
df.columns=[f'{a}{b}' for a, b in df.columns]
print (df)
   ac  ad  bc  bd
0   1   1   2   2
1   1   2   2   4
2   1   3   2   6
```

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear at all, i' ve just edited it

Comment: @Kaoutar - Answer was edited.

Comment: Thank you @jezrael , i've seen this method before, i am wondering if there is some elegant one-line code alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

### Easy solution

```
pd.concat((mat2.mul(mat1[c], axis=0).add_prefix(c) for c in mat1), axis=1)
```

---

```
   ac  ad  bc  bd
0   1   1   2   2
1   1   2   2   4
2   1   3   2   6
```